# Django-haystack with sharded database

Tags: django, solr, sharding, django-haystack

I need to split database to multiple hosts by user ids.

```
DB1        DB2         DB3
---------------------------
User1      User2       User3
User4      User5       User6
```

But how can I add all of them to index?

I can't do it with:

```
def index_queryset(self):
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this of course depends on your app regarding User.

If you have 6 User Models like `User1, User2, ... User6` you could do by writing an own manager for model User, which then will return all Users on `self.get_model().objects.all()` and also could manage your sharded Database.

To know what you like to do and how you did so far it would not to have more information about your current setup